# Servlet hosted on PI to send signal to Arduino

Tags: servlets, arduino, raspberry-pi

So I've set up a basic Spring MVC site that is stored / hosted on Raspberry PI.  My immediate aim is to send a signal to the Arduino that is connected via USB.  Ultimately I'd like to power cycle a device.

I'm not exactly sure on where to go next, I'll have a selection or drop down box or some event on the site, the result of this action will then trigger the Arduino.  It's this A -> B I'm having difficulties with.  I'm not sure whether I can send a parameter that can be monitored or whether there's another better way.  I've hunted around online and found nothing that gives some simple concrete instructions.

If it's possible for the PI / Arduino to monitor a param coming from a page then that would be my ideal solution but, gah, could someone possibly shed some light on this please?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Arduino will have a loop that can do the monitoring. You just need to send proper code on serial port. There is some info here. http://blog.oscarliang.net/connect-raspberry-pi-and-arduino-usb-cable/

Comment: @turbo, thanks for that turbo, certainly helps. :D  Thanks.